# Create Android project programmatically in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, project

In short: Is there a supported way to create an Android project for eclipse (as you would get via the new Android project wizard) programmatically?  Or if not supported, then is there any way at all?  (this is being done within an eclipse plugin)

I've been trying to do this for a while, and it is turning out to be much more difficult than expected.  I took a look at the source for both the New and the Import wizards for Android projects, and found that they both use the NewProjectCreator class.  There seem to be two ways to use this class; one is via the static "create" method, and the other is to construct an instance of NewProjectCreator and call "createAndroidProjects".  However, I'm having trouble getting ahold of all the necessary parameters for either of these.  The static method requires both an IAndroidTarget and a ProjectPopulator, neither of which I can find implementations of (There is an anonymous implementation of ProjectPopulator in the NewProjectWizard class, but pasting this into my code is disastrous in the number of classes and fields it can't find).  The instance method on the other hand requires an IWizardContainer, but I would like to be able to do this without bringing up a wizard.

At the other end of the spectrum, I've tried simply adding and Android nature to the project, but this causes all sorts of build errors, since it doesn't actually change the setup of the project to reflect whatever the Android standards are.  I guess another option is to take this route and try to set up the whole project manually, but I don't know if there are any guidelines for this, or whether the project standards are likely to change.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org) has a script for creating new Android projects from the command line that might get you headed in the right direction.